# How I can use graphql with angular 1.5?

Tags: angularjs, graphql

I have standart factories in my angular app for rest api. I need to configure my angular app for api with **GraphQl**. How i can do this? I now about
[angular2-apollo](https://github.com/apollostack/angular2-apollo) but I have **angular 1.5**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can use [Apollo-Client](https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-client) and just wrap the functions with $q.

Here is an example (Look at the Angular1App folder): https://github.com/robzhu/graphql-demo

Comment: @kamil's answer is more updated, I can't delete mine until it get's to be the accepted answer...

Comment: is it possible to use in AngularJS app which is written in Javascript. I saw your repository in GitHub, it's in typescript. As far as I know for a AngularJS app, a javascript file needs to be added to the app, I didn't find a javascript file for angualr1-apollo.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `angular1-apollo` package.

http://github.com/apollostack/angular1-apollo

Answer (score 0):

Here is a live example. Basically the biggest part is how to set up the client in the config, from there you can just use it like any other service.

https://codesandbox.io/s/l4r87nqj5z

Edit: this actually uses the library in Kamil's answer.

Comment: When trying to do `npm run build` on this example and running it I encounter an error: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e` Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: My guess: js-minification. It only runs on build and angular 1's DI breaks during minification. If it was me I'd run eject and then add the angularjs injection babel plugin or modify the webpack config to remove minification.